# Dynamicaly add multiple integrals to Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I want to use `Manipulate[]` for parameter `n` for this expression. $$\underbrace{\int\limits_\mathbb{R} \dots \int\limits_\mathbb{R}}_nf(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$$

The problem for me is to understand how can I dynamicaly increase the number of integrals just by moving the slider bar for `n` in `Manipulate[]` window.

P.S. I dont care about $f(x_1,x_2, \dots ,x_n)$. It can be even $const$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is by using `Fold`.  I will try it on a randomly generated polynomial,

```
polynomial = 
 Sum[RandomInteger[3, 2].(x[n]^RandomInteger[5, 2]), {n, 5}]
(* 2 + 3 x[1]^5 + x[2]^3 + x[2]^5 + x[3]^3 + 3 x[4]^5 + 3 x[5]^5 *)
```

and I'll use a `TraditionalForm` to give a visual output,

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{TraditionalForm@
    Row@Flatten[{"∫" & /@ Range[n], 
       "f", {"\[DifferentialD]", Subscript[x, #]} & /@ Range[n], "="}],
   Fold[Integrate[#1, #2] &, polynomial, x[#] & /@ Range[n]] /. 
    x[a_] :> Subscript[x, a]}],
 {{n, 1}, 1, 5, 1}]
```

[image]

You could generalize it to use a different variable list, here I'm just using `{x[1],x[2],...}`, but it would be easy to modify it to use, for example, `{α, β, γ}`.  It would also be easy to modify it to do definite integrals as well

Comment: The core thing to focus on is the `Fold[Integrate[#1, #2] &, polynomial, varlist]` where `varlist` is the variables that will be integrated over.  You could have a larger `varlist` and use `Fold[Integrate[#1, #2] &, polynomial, varlist[[;;n]]]` and only the first `n` variables will be integrated over.  The rest is window dressing to make it clear visually what is being integrated.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. I am new to Mathematica and you answer is very helpful. I am going to experiment wit it a little now, to understand everything.

Answer (score 2):

With `Sequence[]` combined with a function to create the necessary variables should do the trick.

```
Manipulate[
  Integrate[f@@#, Sequence@@Reverse[#]] &[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n]]
, {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

`Reverse[#]` provides the correct ordering of the variables. `Symbol["x" <> ToString[#] &` creates a numbered variable to be used. It can be replaced with something that suits your needs.
By replacing that part with something like

```
Function[arg, Symbol[arg <> ToString[#]]] /@ {"x", "a", "b"} &
```

, definite Integrals are also possible.